# No -debug flag for llvm opt

Tags: llvm

I am using "Support/Debug.h" to introduce debug statements in my pass. In order to enable the debug mode, I am required to run opt with the -debug flag, however opt has no such flag.

```
opt: Unknown command line argument '-debug'.  Try: 'opt -help'
opt: Did you mean '-debugify'?
```

I tried both with the releasebuild and the debugBuild version of the opt binary.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the -debug flag does not exist if you build llvm with the NDEBUG macro set, which I assume most versions shipped with Linux distros will do. I haven't tested, but you probably have to build llvm from source if you haven't already done so.

Answer (score 0):

You need a debug build of LLVM (i.e. `opt`) and your pass (i.e. use `-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug` instead of `-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release`)